# Smart Search on webform with sqlserver and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an application that contain a products directory and the database structred as the following:

```
CategoryTable
{
    Category_ID
    Category_Name
}

CountryTable
{
    Country_ID
    Countr_Name
}

ProductTable
{
    Product_ID
    Category_ID
    Country_ID
    Product_Name
}
```

I may have a product with a category in the specific country
I want to create a textbox on my directory webform and search for a product as the folowing: Product in country ex: iPad in germany, chair in spain. ... etc.

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible with SQL. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I am still in research stage and I am collecting ideas, I see something like this smart search on facebook

Comment: You'll need to break this down into two parts, the SQL part and the asp.net part.  Use a stored procedure for the SQL part with parameters to pass in the category and country names.

Comment: How I will translate the phrase written in the search box? it will be a statment

Comment: That is a complicated asp.net problem that I would not know about.  Did you do any searching?  A quick Google search took me to here: http://www.ifdefined.com/blog/post/2009/02/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx

Comment: actually I read about a full-text search but I don't know how to apply the search as I need